# Jquery-ui $("#button").click dont work at random times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

At random times the buttons with a score not work. I dont understand why? Is there is a problem with js code? Tried it in chrome and ie

http://live.tennisofficial.ru/dev/operator/mobile/chair2.php#live

p.s. some php errors couz I manually turned off authorization.
there are looks like a lot of code but there is just a lot of if's

**added**: strange, Im commented everything in pointOne,Two function except 
`console.log("Point1 clicked");`

and still dont work S:

**added**: removed everything... still have a problem

**added**: it works well with an `<a>`. So there is a problem with a buttton mechanics? I will change buttons for an `<a>` but still interesting why buttons didnt work? I hear smth about 300ms between button clicks, is it a problem?

```
<script>

$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#live",function(){ // When entering page live

  $("#pointOne").val("0");
  $("#pointTwo").val("0");
  $("#pointOne").button("refresh");
  $("#pointTwo").button("refresh");
  $point1 = 0;
  $point2 = 0;
  $sets1 = new Array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  $sets2 = new Array (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);
  $score = new Array(0, 15, 30, 40, "Ad", "-", "Ad");
  $currentset = 1;


  //reload score
  $("#gamescore").text("0:0");
  $("#gamescore2").text("Sets: 0:0 0:0 0:0");
});

/*get id of match*/

/*END OF get id of match*/


$("#pointOne").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Point1 clicked");

});

$("#pointTwo").on("click", function() {
    console.log("Point2 clicked");

});



</script>
```

Comment: pls include code in question. its hard for people to help if they need to go to another link just to check the code

Comment: oh, sry, working on it

Comment: Isolate your problem.

Answer (score 0):

try adding:

```
 $("#pointOne").click(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 ...
```